# Find a surjective homomorphism of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have difficulties with this task

Find a homomorphism $\Phi : (G, \circ) \to (G, \circ)$, that is surjective but not injective.

I tried to find such a homomorphism, by finding a surjective function, yet functions I tried were not homomorphisms. And then I end up with $Ker(\Phi)=\{e_G\}$. So I found an isomorphism.

Comment: What is $G$? If $G$ is a finite group, this can't be achieved for example.

Comment: You could take $G$ to be the direct product $\times_{i \ge 0} C_2$ of infinitely many copies of the cyclic group of order $2$, and then define $\Phi$ to map the $i$-th direct factor to the $(i+1)$-st for all $i \ge 0$.

Comment: @Baloown $G$ is not specified. I tried only finite sets and that was the problem. This question really is a duplicate.